# Beans not recognized from spring-context.xml while loading the XML file as a part of a (Spring Boot Application) jar file

Tags: java, xml, spring, spring-boot, spring-integration

I have an assignment wherein after creating a jar file using Spring Boot, I have to load it using URLClassLoader in a Java class to execute it. Issue is that although the jar file runs fine when launched directly but when I try to load it in a Java class using the following code, it fails.

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{       
        // Getting the jar URL which contains target class
        URL[] classLoaderUrls = new URL[]{new URL("file:///C://Users\\CHH7KOR\\Documents\\POC\\BootDemo\\target\\BootDemo-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar")};

        // Create a new URLClassLoader 
        URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = new URLClassLoader(classLoaderUrls);

        Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(urlClassLoader);
            System.out.println("ASHD:"+Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());
        // Load the target class
        Class<?> beanClass = urlClassLoader.loadClass("sample.integration.SampleIntegrationApplication");

        // Create a new instance from the loaded class
        Constructor<?> constructor = beanClass.getConstructor();
        Object beanObj = constructor.newInstance();           

        // Getting a method from the loaded class and invoke it
        Method method = beanClass.getMethod("doAllFunctions");
        method.invoke(beanObj);         
}
```

The error that I get when I run this is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at Sample.main(Sample.java:33)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'ftpInboundChannel' is defined
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:698)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1175)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:284)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:202)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1060)
    at sample.integration.SampleIntegrationApplication.doAllFunctions(SampleIntegrationApplication.java:57)
    ... 5 more
```

Here `ftpInboundChannel` is a channel configured as a part of `spring-config.xml`

Comment: Why on earth are you creating this contraption? Also why do you think creating a new instance of your application class will do anything? You would need to call the main method for that...

Comment: @Deinum The requirement is such and hence the flow.

Comment: To answer Ur question, the function being called is actually being hit but the point where the context creation comes up, it fails to read the beans from the context.xml file.

Comment: Why on earth do you have that requirement... It is ugly, error prone and doesn't add anything but complexity.

Comment: Also I do not think the call to the main method is necessary as the instance created is sufficient to call any functions of the concerned class and I'm able to do so as well.

Comment: Deinum, well would U please suggest an alternative for the below mentioned requirement?

Comment: Requirement: I have to load and execute the jars on fly as a part of Business Requirments

Comment: `java -jar your.jar` and the main class will be executed...

Comment: Sir I have to do that using a java class and not the CMD

Comment: Then you aren't exciting anything "on the fly"... As you would need to modify your java code each time you need a jar. Also how are you going to execute that piece of code of yours?

Comment: Well this is a POC that we are doing Deinum and we want to test the feasibility of this approach because we don't want to bundle this using the OSGI model. So the bigger picture is to wrap these jar components and feed it to an established orchestration

Comment: Then why even use Spring Boot... Still it is an ugly contraption and seems like a workaround for a misunderstood framework... But that is from my side of the screen. The method you are invoking must first bootstrap the application including all the configuration (that part is probably something you forgot) else it won't work. Basically your method needs to do the same as the `main` method when you simply start the jar.

Comment: The reason why we are using this approach is because while using OSGI model we were having certain bottlenecks in deployment of jars.

Comment: I understand what you say but how to make it happen is what I want to know.Any snippet that you can put up here?

Comment: The class which I'm trying to load has basically a main method which calls the method where the logic of creating the context and thereafter polling the channels to receive messages are written

Comment: But that main method is useless... That doesn't do anything because you aren't calling it and it will not be invoked because you aren't using the command line...

Comment: Precisely so..The main class was there to test the functionality alone. Very simple thing is that I want the class loaded to also load the spring-context.xml file and get the beans constructed. If you can  help with some working code on this, it would be really helpful.