# Unable to transfer/copy files in between folders with annotation based FTPInbound Adapter in Spring Integration

Tags: ftp, spring-integration

I used the following code to do file transfer using FTP Inbound Adapter but the files do not get transferred. Any clues on this would be really helpful.

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow ftpIn()
{


    DefaultFtpSessionFactory defSession=new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    defSession.setUsername("anonymous");
    defSession.setPassword("anonymous!!");
    defSession.setPort(21);
    defSession.setHost("10.47.116.158");


    File localDirectory=new File("C:\\FTP_Default");
    File remoteDirectory=new File("C:\\FilesFromServer");




    return IntegrationFlows.from(Ftp.inboundAdapter(defSession).localDirectory(localDirectory).remoteDirectory("C:\\FilesFromServer")
            .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true),
            e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(50)).autoStartup(true))
            .channel(this.inputChannel())
            .handle(System.out::println).get();



}
 @Bean
     public DirectChannel inputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
```

Comment: Also the adapter is only able to read files from "localDirectory" and not the "remoteDirectory" which it ideally should because "localDirectory" is where the files should be transferred.

Comment: I'm scared a bit of that your remoteDirectory on the disk C:. Can you confirm that you can pick up files from there using regular FTP client on your OS not Spring Integration or Java At all?

Comment: Make a SessionFactory as bean, too

Comment: @Artem Correct my local machine here behaves as a FTP server wherein the default server folder is "C:\\FTP_Default" and I have configured my Java class as a FTP client for which the default directory is "C:\\FilesFromServer". And yes I can achieve the same functionality using simple FTP client or Java as well but I wanted to so it using the Spring Integration FTP adapter.

Comment: I finally figured out that for the adapter to detect the root server directory we have to set this variable of the session: DefaultFtpSessionFactory.DEFAULT_REMOTE_WORKING_DIRECTORY; and it shall work smoothly

Comment: @ArtemBilan May I also request you to comment on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34611165/beans-not-recognized-from-spring-context-xml-while-loading-the-xml-file-as-a-par ?

Comment: Sorry, your comment about `DefaultFtpSessionFactory.DEFAULT_REMOTE_WORKING_DIRECTORY` isn't clear to me. Would be better to share your fix here as an answer to finish this question. And you even can accept your own. And I'll will vote then. :)

Comment: Sorry, I can't help you with that other `ClassLoader` question because ti isn't clear why you would like to deal with such a low stuff, rather than use `Process` to run `java -jar` for your purpose...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to the above mentioned issue was :

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow ftpIn()
{


    DefaultFtpSessionFactory defSession=new DefaultFtpSessionFactory();
    defSession.setUsername(userId);
    defSession.setPassword(password);
    defSession.setPort(port);
    defSession.setHost(host);
    defSession.setClientMode(2);
    **String remoteDirectory=DefaultFtpSessionFactory.DEFAULT_REMOTE_WORKING_DIRECTORY;**



    File localDirectory=new File("C:\\FilesFromServer");




    return IntegrationFlows.from(Ftp.inboundAdapter(defSession).localDirectory(localDirectory).remoteDirectory(remoteDirectory)
            .autoCreateLocalDirectory(true),
            e -> e.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(50)))
            .channel(this.inputChannel())
            .handle(m -> System.out.println(m.getPayload())).get();


}
 @Bean
     public DirectChannel inputChannel() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }
```

Comment: The variable remoteDirectory has to be set to "DefaultFtpSessionFactory.DEFAULT_REMOTE_WORKING_DIRECTORY;" as shown above and used to populate the remoteDirectory for Ftp.inboundAdapter

Comment: @Artem as far as the ClassLoader question is concerned, may I explain to you that we are trying to package the Spring Integration App code in an executable jar file using Spring boot and load it during runtime. Now this can be achieved using simple Runtime Process, however the expectation is that the function in the jar should return value which is to be fed to some other code.This could not be achieved using simple Runtime Process and hence the URIClassLoader approach where we are able to invoke a method an return a value to be used further.

Comment: @Artem Please suggest if you see an alternative for the same